# Use variables in sed along with !d

Tags: sed

MacOS. I have the following file from which I have to delete all lines between `first` and `last` including `first`. `last` appears multiple times in the file and I don't want to delete it.

```
$ cat sample.tf
some lines 1
some random 2
first
vdsvdfsv
vdsvdfsv
dfvbfbvfvfrver
bvevreverv
last
vfver
vever
end
last
some last
end
$
```

I am able to do it with following command

```
$ sed '/^first/,/^last/{/^last/!d;}' sample.tf
some lines 1
some random 2
last
vfver
vever
end
last
some last
end
$
```

But the challenge I have is my `first` and `last` are variables. To use variables, I have to use `"` and tried following command but it is trying to convert `!d` into the command from history. How can I achieve what I am trying to do.

```
$ echo $startstring
first
$ echo $endstring
last
$
$ sed "/^$startstring/,/^$endstring/{/^$endstring/!d;}" sample.tf
sed "/^$startstring/,/^$endstring/{/^$endstring/diff main.tf main.tf.good ;}" sample.tf
sed: 1: "/^first/,/^last/{/^last ...": extra characters at the end of d command
$

$ !d
diff main.tf main.tf.good
$
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping it?  `sed '/^first/,/^last/{/^first/\!d;}' sample.tf`

Comment: @Zak Escaping didn't work.


`$ sed "/^$startstring/,/^$endstring/{/^$endstring/\!d;}" sample.tf
sed: 1: "/^first/,/^last/{/^last ...": invalid command code \
$`

Comment: You can mix-and-match quotes.  `sed "/^$startstring/,/^$endstring/{/^$endstring/"'!d;}' sample.tf`

Comment: Is this Linux? OR a *Nix like os -- IE MacOS

Comment: @WilliamPursell mix-and-match of quotes worked. Thanks you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can you post it as answer so I can accept it? I guess this is the correct process. This is my first question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion from @William Pursell to mix-and-match quotes worked for me.

```
sed "/^$startstring/,/^$endstring/{/^$endstring/"'!d;}' sample.tf
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^'"${startstring}"'/,/^'"${endstring}"'/{/^'"${endstring}"'/!d}' file
```

Use single quotes to prevent shell interpolation of the `!` character.

Alternative:

```
sed -n '/^'"{startstring}"'/{:a;n;/^'"{endstring}"'/!ba};p' file
```